# jquery/validation plugin/object literals: selecting multiple checkboxes

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox

Ok, I've tried to read up on this but I'm stumped. Unfortunately it's a case of me not understanding javascript properly.

When processing a form with jqueries validation plugin, you send the variables to the php mailer using literal notation:

```
  submitHandler: function() { 
  $.post("includes/mail-form.php",
  {  
  age : $("#form-age-id").val(),
  email : $("#form-email-id").val(), 
  name : $("#form-name-i").val(),
```

Which I understand. the variable age is being assigned the value from the element. When I have multiple checkboxes though, I can't use:

```
$("input.checkboxes:checked').val()
```

as it will only select the first matched element, so i need to iterate over the multiple checkboxes using a function similar to

```
 var allVals = [];
 $('input.orthodontic-medical-form-disease:checked').each(function() {
         allVals.push($(this).val());
      });
 return allVals;
```

What I don't understand is how I assign the return value to the literal. I've tried

```
  submitHandler: function() { 
     $.post("includes/mail-form.php",
  {  
  age : $("#form-age-id").val(),
  email : $("#form-email-id").val(), 
  name : $("#form-name-i").val(),
         checkboxes : function(){
           var allVals = [];
    $('input.orthodontic-medical-form-disease:checked').each(function() {
         allVals.push($(this).val());
         });a
           return allVals;
         }
```

But I'm guessing that's assigning the actual function itself to the variable, not the returned value. Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
checkboxes : $('input.orthodontic-medical-form-disease:checked').map(function() {
                 return $(this).val();
             }).get() // returns array of checked values
```

Alternatively, encapsulate your 'checkbox value getting' logic into a named function:

```
function getCheckedVals() {
    var rv = $('input.orthodontic-medical-form-disease:checked').map(function() {
                 return $(this).val();
             }).get();
    return rv;
}
```

and just call it:

```
checkboxes: getCheckedVals()
```

Comment: that works, I just had to append toString() at the end. so:
    $('input.orthodontic-medical-form-disease:checked').map(function() {return $(this).val();}).get().toString();

I think I was misunderstanding the object literal layout. Because of the lack strict type, I didn't realise I was passing an array or function object to the php, and not a string like I should of. Thanks!